# Convert json string to npgsql jsonb for use with dapper

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I am using C# with Dapper and i would like to insert JSON to a table with a field of JSONB kind.

My Code:

```
var requestUUID = await PostgresCon.ExecuteScalarAsync<Guid>(sSQL, new
        {
            jsonb_field = myJsonString,

        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So I am receiving the error "42804: column "jsonb_field" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text"

or maybe I need to Deserialize using System.Text.Json like this code:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<..what Type to enter here?...>(requestJson)
```

but what is the current type to enter?

Thanks,
AG

Comment: non of `"jsonb" dapper` internert search which points to similar question here on stackoverflow work? There is one which uses ICustomQueryParameter and one which uses cast ... they look promising

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Selvin (Thanks you!) I have ended with this following code:

```
public class JsonBParameter : ICustomQueryParameter
{
    private readonly string json;

    public JsonBParameter(string json)
    {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public void AddParameter(IDbCommand command, string name)
    {
        var parameter = (NpgsqlParameter)command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = name;
        parameter.Value = json;
        parameter.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}

var requestUUID = await PostgresCon.ExecuteScalarAsync<Guid>(sSQL, new
    {
        jsonb_field = new JsonBParameter(myJsonString),

    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```